# oracle SQL - How to find line that was skipped in other table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_part_1
(
  LOGID NUMBER 
, TIMESTAMP DATE 
, TASK VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)
, TERMINALIP VARCHAR2(256 CHAR) 
) 

CREATE TABLE tbl_part_2
(
  LOGID NUMBER 
, MREC_ID VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) NOT NULL 
, SUBTASK VARCHAR2(200 CHAR) 
, USER VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) 
, TRANSACTIONID VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) 
) 

CREATE TABLE tbl_full_record 
(
  REC_ID VARCHAR2(32 CHAR) NOT NULL 
, TMSTAMP DATE 
, USER VARCHAR2(250 CHAR) 
, META_RECORD VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR)   
, DATA_RECORD CLOB 
)
```

In the column "META_RECORD" I got an XML:

```
<Meta_Record>
    <TimeStamp>(DATE TIME HERE)</TimeStamp>
    <User>(USER NAME HERE)</User> <!-- USER from tbl_part_2 -->
    <TerminalIP>(USER IP HERE)</TerminalIP>  <!-- TERMINALIP from tbl_part_1 -->
    <Task>(USER TASK HERE)</Task> <!-- TASK from tbl_part_1 -->
    <SubTask>(USER SUBTASK HERE)</SubTask>  <!-- SUBTASK from tbl_part_2 -->
    <MetaRecordID>(MREC_ID HERE)</MetaRecordID>  <!-- MREC_ID from tbl_part_2 -->
    <TransactionID>(TRANSACTIONID HERE)</TransactionID>   <!-- TRANSACTIONID from tbl_part_2 -->
</Meta_Record>
```

The Table "tbl_full_record" is holding same data as "tbl_part_1" and "tbl_part_2".
But currently I am missing one in row in "tbl_full_record" (or got one to much in "tbl_part_1" with "tbl_part_2").
Note: There are several "tbl_full_record" (one for each month of the year) but only once the "tbl_part_1+2"
The mapping has to be done via the "META_RECORD" field of the "tbl_full_record"

I would like to know how I do find out what is the missing/too much row? 
How would I set up a query to get that, that is as well performant assuming that "tbl_part_1+2" has about 20.000.000 lines and "tbl_full_record" has some 1.500.000?

Comment: Do you have foreign keys that relate these tables?

Comment: Can you explain the exact rule to match `tbl_part_1`, `tbl_part_2` with `tbl_full_record`? It's not obvious from the explanation.

Comment: I added some info for the mapping to make it more clear. There are no foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming log_id and rec_id are same.

Extra rows in tbl_part_1 , tbl_part_2 :

```
select tp1.*, tp2.* from tbl_part_1 tp1, tbl_part_2 tp2
      where tp1.logid = tp2.logid
   --add necessary join conditions
  and not exists ( select * from tbl_full_record tf
                    where tp1.logid = tf.rec_id
                    --add any correlated join conditions
                );
```

Comment: `tp1.log_id` and `tf.rec_id` are of a different data type. Oracle won't run the query.

Comment: Without data, it ran fine in 12c. I will put some data and test. :-P

Comment: I tried a join, seems like Oracle doing implicit cast "varchar2" to "number" if the data in the column is convertible to the "number" datatype. As long as the column contains numeric data, it will work fine.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that. Upvoting.

Comment: Unfortunately p1.log_id and tf.rec_id are not the same - I added some info to explain the mapping in the question.

Comment: Hi @PaulEdison , How META_RECORD is related to tbl_part_1 and tbl_part_2. If you can make it clear about the relationships we can solve.

Comment: @SameerPradhan: I added in the question in the description of the META_RECORD the "links" to the tbl_part_1 & 2